# Consulta recursiva não retorna registros quando o produto pai e o produto filho têm o mesmo código

Tags: sql-server, recursão, relacionamento, path

Tenho uma tabela que mapeia uma linha de produção. 
 
Os campos são: 
Product: Produto de saída da máquina. 
ParentProduct: Produto de entrada. 
Machine: Codigo da máquina. 
 
Estou usando CTE´s para obter os dados de forma recursiva.
Isso funciona quando os códigos Product e ParentProduct são diferentes

```
use DB_TEST

DECLARE @TableTest TABLE ( 
    Product nvarchar(10) null,
    ParentProduct  nvarchar(10) null,
    Machine nvarchar(10) null
)

begin

    insert into @TableTest values ('Product1', null, 'MACH1' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product2', null, 'MACH2'  );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product3', null, 'MACH3'  );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product4', 'Product1', 'MACH1' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product5', 'Product1', 'MACH1' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product6', 'Product2', 'MACH2' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product7', 'Product4', 'MACH2' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product8', 'Product4', 'MACH3' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product9', 'Product5', 'MACH1' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product10', 'Product6', 'MACH2' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product11', 'Product8', 'MACH3' );

;WITH tree AS
(
    SELECT P.Machine, p.Product, p.ParentProduct, [level] = 1, [path] = cast(p.Product as varchar(100))
    FROM @TableTest p
    WHERE p.ParentProduct IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT P2.Machine, p2.Product, p2.ParentProduct,  [level] = tree.[level] + 1, 
           [path] = Cast(tree.[path] + ' > ' + cast(p2.Product as varchar(10)) as varchar(100))
    FROM @TableTest p2 INNER JOIN tree ON tree.Product = p2.ParentProduct 
)
SELECT * FROM tree 
Order by machine
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

end;
```

Resultado CORRETO.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando os códigos são iguais (ParentProduct = Product) o produto não aparece no resultado.

Nesse exemplo o produto de saída 'product8' tem o mesmo código que o produto de entrada.(Isso é uma regra aqui da empresa. Alguns produtos podem ter o mesmo código de entrada e saída.)

```
insert into @TableTest values ('Product1', null, 'MACH1' );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product2', null, 'MACH2'  );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product3', null, 'MACH3'  );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product4', 'Product1', 'MACH1' );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product5', 'Product1', 'MACH1' );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product6', 'Product2', 'MACH2' );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product7', 'Product4', 'MACH2' );

/* ---- AQUI O PRODUTO DE ENTRADA É IGUAL AO DE SAÍDA. -----*/
insert into @TableTest values ('Product8', 'Product8', 'MACH3' );

insert into @TableTest values ('Product9', 'Product5', 'MACH1' );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product10', 'Product6', 'MACH2' );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product11', 'Product8', 'MACH3' );
```

Resultado INCORRETO. 
O produto 'product8' e seus relacionamentos desaparecem do resultado da consulta.

[image: a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Precisava mostrar o 'path' ou o caminho, tipo um 'breadcrumb', do produto 'product8' dessa forma: 

Product1 > Product4 > *Product8* > *Product8* > Product11


O produto precisa aparecer 2 vezes no caminho.

É possível obter esse resultado? Como devo proceder?**

Comment: Favor traduzir a sua pergunta.

Comment: Aqui no stackoverflow em português as perguntas devem ser em português.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro realçar que o resultado para a segunda lista de dados não está errado. A ligação entre o Product 8 e o(s) seu(s) ParentProduct não existe, ou desapareceu, entre a primeira lista de inserções e a segunda, logo não constam no resultado da consulta.
Também percebo o porque de faltar, pois se a ligação existisse a query entrava em loop, pois ficaria "presa" nas iterações entre product e parentproduct.

Como possível solução segue o exemplo:

```
DECLARE @TableTest TABLE ( 
    Product nvarchar(10) null,
    ParentProduct  nvarchar(10) null,
    Machine nvarchar(10) null
)

begin

    insert into @TableTest values ('Product1', null, 'MACH1' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product2', null, 'MACH2'  );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product3', null, 'MACH3'  );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product4', 'Product1', 'MACH1' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product5', 'Product1', 'MACH1' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product6', 'Product2', 'MACH2' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product7', 'Product4', 'MACH2' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product8', 'Product4', 'MACH3' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product8', 'Product8', 'MACH3' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product9', 'Product5', 'MACH1' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product10', 'Product6', 'MACH2' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product11', 'Product8', 'MACH3' );

;WITH tree AS
(
    SELECT P.Machine, p.Product, p.ParentProduct, [level] = 1, [path] = cast(p.Product as varchar(100))
    FROM @TableTest p
    WHERE p.ParentProduct IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT P2.Machine, p2.Product, p2.ParentProduct,  [level] = tree.[level] + 1, 
           [path] = Cast(tree.[path] + ' > ' + cast(p2.Product as varchar(10)) as varchar(100))
    FROM @TableTest p2 INNER JOIN tree ON tree.Product = p2.ParentProduct 
        AND (tree.Product <> p2.Product or tree.Machine <> p2.Machine OR tree.ParentProduct <> p2.ParentProduct)
)
SELECT * FROM tree 
Order by machine
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

end;
```

Note que apenas foram adicionadas duas linhas ao seu código de origem, uma nas inserções para criar a relação entre produto e seu "progenitor" e uma para quebrar o tal "loop" no union quando product e parent são o mesmo na clausula where. Espero que ajude!